# get page from pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I have my pagination which works perfectly, but I want to find one comment from the database and get the page where the comment is displayed.

For example, in my database there are 100 comments and I can see 10 comments per page. That means that I have 10 pages of comments. If I want to locate comment number 25, it should be displayed on the third page but limited from comment number 21 to comment number 30. And then display it as link
`<a href="comments.php?page=3">Comment</a>`.

Here is my pagination code:

```
$count = $con->query($sqlc)->num_rows;

if(isset($_GET["page"])){
    $page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET["page"]);           
} else {
    $page = 1;                
}

$perPage = 10;
$lastPage = ceil($count/$perPage);

if($page < 1){
    $page = 1;                
} else if($page > $lastPage){
    $page = $lastPage;
}

if($lastPage !=1){                    
    if($page != $lastPage){
        $next = $page + 1;
        $pagination.='<a id="prevPage" href="?page='.$next.'">Older comments</a>';
    }

    if($page != 1){
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $pagination.='<a id="nextPage" href="?page='.$prev.'">Newer comments</a>';
    }  
}

$limit = "LIMIT ".($page-1) * $perPage . ", ".$perPage;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC ".$limit;
$query = $con->query($sql);

while($rowCom = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    // Display Comments
}
```

Comment: Some kind of loop until you find the one you're looking for will probably do it

Comment: i dont have any idea to solve this can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to compute the page number :

```
$pageNb = $commentNumber / $perPage + 1;
```

where $commentNumber is the number of the comment, that I understand you already know. then, you just write

```
<a href="comments.php?page=<?php echo $pageNb;?>">Comment</a>
```

I hope this helps

---

If you need to know what is the comment position, things get a little more complicated.

One solution, is, while generating the pagination, to save somewhere an array with all the comments ids, in their order. This way, you can find comment position by calling $commentArray[$commentId].

Another solution is to save the position of the comments in the database table. So you add another column 'position' to the comment table, and populate it. This way, you can find the position of a particular comment.

Both solutions try to avoid a second iteration through all the comments which can be consumming.

Comment: but i want to get comment number from comment id's which are radnom numbers for example i have 100 records like i say before and id's are like this (12, 41, 58, 92, 68....) and i know how to get total count of all comments but i dont know how to get ordinal number for example comment id 58